# Find out if database already exists in ORMLite

Tags: ormlite

I want to tell ORMLite to create a database if one already doesn't. How can I find out if the database that I want to construct is there. (I'm using H2 DB with it.)

Answer (score 0):

> How can I find out if the database that I want to construct is there. (I'm using H2 DB with it.)

This is database dependent.  Looks like for H2 you can add something to the database URL.  See this URL from their docs:

> http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#database_only_if_exists

To quote:

> By default, when an application calls DriverManager.getConnection(url, ...) and the database specified in the URL does not yet exist, a new (empty) database is created. In some situations, it is better to restrict creating new databases, and only allow to open existing databases. To do this, add `;IFEXISTS=TRUE` to the database URL. In this case, if the database does not already exist, an exception is thrown when trying to connect. The connection only succeeds when the database already exists.